# Eclipse Papyrus and UML Expansion Region

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I'm trying to use an expansion region in Eclipse Papyrus but it won't work.

I've got a `ReadStructuralFeatureAction` that reads a `StructuralFeature` `cars`. For these cars I the need to calculate if the load is to heavy. Therefore I'm taking an `ExpansionRegion` and attach an `ExpansionNode` to. But then I can't add `InputPins` to the `ExpansionNode`.
If I create a single `InputPins` I get`The feature 'inputElement' of '<Expansion Region> ...' with 0 values must have at least 1 values`. If I try to connect the result of the Action directly to the `ExpansioNode` I get `An edge that has a source in an exception handler structured node must also have its target in the handler, and vice versa.`

Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO [Modelio](http://www.modelio.org) seems like a really nice open source alternative for now. Not only it looks eye candy, but it has an Expansion Region working flawlessly as well as other yummy features. Though I had to add *parallel* and *iterative* stereotypes and requested to show them instead of icons for Expansion Region.

Answer (score 1):

According to UML 2.4 specification ExpansionRegion must be connected to the other activity nodes through ExpensionNode as depicted below

[image]

Our error "Expansion Region ... must have at least 1 values" might be due to the fact that ExpansionRegion should have at least one as input elements i.e. one ExpansionNode.

Hoping it helps.

Comment: Your diagram shows what I didn't get to work. I created an `ExpansionRegion` and wanted to add an `ExpansionNode`. When I pull the `ExpansionNode` to the region nothing happens. Not even in the background.

Comment: What is your version of Papyrus ?

Comment: I got version 0.10.2v20140229

Comment: There is [a bug about expansion region being not usable](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425579).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to use eclipse older version “eclipse Indigo“.